# How to select records not selected by a sql statement?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following sql query below.  I am interested in all records that are not selected by this sql query.  I have made an attempt below but i have an error in my SQL syntax.  Please can someone advise?

```
SELECT *
FROM codec_status NOT IN
  (SELECT *
   FROM codec_status
   WHERE version_er_r='0'
     OR ntpStatus_er_r='0'
     OR stAvailable_er_r='0'
     OR RXRate_er_r='0'
     OR TXRate_er_r='0'
     OR DefaultCallRate_er_r='0'
     OR RemoteView_er_r='0'
     OR VoiceVlan_er_r='0'
     OR Transport_er_r='0'
   )
```

Comment: " i have an error in my SQL syntax" then why not share the error message, why are you making us guess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say the main ID from table codec_status is just id. Then You should do it like that:

```
SELECT * FROM codec_status where id  NOT IN 
(SELECT id FROM codec_status WHERE version_er_r='0' OR ntpStatus_er_r='0' OR stAvailable_er_r='0' OR RXRate_er_r='0' OR TXRate_er_r='0' OR DefaultCallRate_er_r='0' OR RemoteView_er_r='0' OR VoiceVlan_er_r='0' OR Transport_er_r='0')
```

Comment: I am getting from MYsqli : '#1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)'

Comment: are You sure u selected only ID in my subquery ? (the one in brackets)

Comment: Thanks dude! that was it.  the query works and all the number finally add up.

Answer (score 1):

You should learn logic gates that will help you more in these conditions. Here just use [De Morgan's Theorem](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/computer_logical_organization/demorgan_theroems.htm)

```
SELECT * FROM codec_status NOT IN (SELECT * FROM codec_status WHERE version_er_r='0' OR ntpStatus_er_r='0' OR stAvailable_er_r='0' OR RXRate_er_r='0' OR TXRate_er_r='0' OR DefaultCallRate_er_r='0' OR RemoteView_er_r='0' OR VoiceVlan_er_r='0' OR Transport_er_r='0')
```

Replace it with this

```
SELECT * FROM codec_status WHERE version_er_r<>'0' AND ntpStatus_er_r<>'0' AND stAvailable_er_r<>'0' AND RXRate_er_r<>'0' AND TXRate_er_r<>'0' AND DefaultCallRate_er_r<>'0' AND RemoteView_er_r<>'0' AND VoiceVlan_er_r<>'0' AND Transport_er_r<>'0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Some DBMS have the MINUS operator:

```
select * from tablename where ....
minus
select * from tablename where ....
```

unfortunately MySQL does not support the minus operator. If your table has an ID column you could write something like this:

```
select * from codec_status
where
  id NOT IN (select ID
             from
               codec_status
             where ....)
```

(be carefoul when using NOT IN especially if your subquery returns NULL values, but if ID is a primary key you should have no problems).

Anyway you could write your query as:

```
select * from codec_status
where NOT (
  version_er_r='0'
  OR ntpStatus_er_r='0'
  OR stAvailable_er_r='0'
  OR RXRate_er_r='0'
  OR TXRate_er_r='0'
  OR DefaultCallRate_er_r='0'
  OR RemoteView_er_r='0'
  OR VoiceVlan_er_r='0'
  OR Transport_er_r='0'
)
```

even here you have to be careful about null values (if all columns are null you want the rows to be returned in your first query or in the second one?)

Answer (score 0):

Just use `not`

```
SELECT *
   FROM codec_status
   WHERE NOT 
    (version_er_r='0'
     OR ntpStatus_er_r='0'
     OR stAvailable_er_r='0'
     OR RXRate_er_r='0'
     OR TXRate_er_r='0'
     OR DefaultCallRate_er_r='0'
     OR RemoteView_er_r='0'
     OR VoiceVlan_er_r='0'
     OR Transport_er_r='0')
```